# Same font, but it looks different on different places

Tags: fonts, shopify, font-face

I can't seem to figure out why this font looks different in difference places. I'm using "Josefin Sans", sans-serif. From my screenshot below, the text on the tabs are what it should look like. The part below that say "Unisex Cut, refer to size chart...", this looks like someone look a bite out of some parts of the font. But if I view this on mobile, then there are no issues.

What could it be?

Here is my site if it helps to look on there: shopbarkrangers.com

Thank you!!

["Josefin Sans", sans-serif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rf5fe.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This font is rendered this way.
In the tabs you use 16px font, and in second part 18px. 
Go to fonts.google.com and preview Josefin Sans, at 16px and below it loses its special 'bitten' outline.

Comment: Ahh I see. Thank you so so much! I'm just starting to learn HTML/CSS and I thought I did something strange in my CSS to caused that. Good to know that the fonts will vary! :)